# How do I form fill a website login page which has an frame/iframe component?

Tags: javascript, authentication, iframe, frame

I'm trying create a basic javascript code to form fill a but it only works when using the display (login.html) frame.

```
getElementsByName('loginID')[0].value = '{username}';
```

If I'm using the top site, then it doesn't work, but if I use the display (login.html) frame it works.  The element has the  tab so I assume it's using frames/iframes?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
var ifrm = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]; //this can be changed to frame if needed

var innerDoc = ifrm.contentDocument || ifrm.contentWindow.document; 

innerDoc.getElementsByName('LOGIN_NAME')[0].value = '{username}';
innerDoc.getElementsByName('LOGIN_PASSWORD')[0].value = '{password}';

var target = innerDoc.getElementsByName('save')[0];
target.click();
```

This allowed me to access the frame and form fill the username and password!

Hope this helps